# Driving a Web Site using a server-side scripting language & excel, instead of mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, excel, web

Is it possible to drive a Web Site using a server-side scripting language & excel, instead of mySQL?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this? You're probably better to use a Flat database file, noSQL solution over Excel.

Comment: Not possible in case of large website. if small level application like to use very limited number of users then may be possible. But not a good practice at all for any level of application.

Comment: I receive a bulk of my information from excel sheets which i need for the website.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh only 10 users

Comment: Convert it to a more manageable format when you receive it.

Comment: @Jite recomended formats?

Comment: Then go for it. And don't say it a website. Also it's depend on functionality that it required database or not because working with excel is very tedious task.

Comment: Well, personally I'd probably just add it to a proper database. :P

Comment: Yes me too. For small or large application working with database is easy and excellent

Comment: I assume you are avoiding converting your Excel spreadsheet to MySQL because you are not prepared for a learning curve with using php or other server side language and MySQL?  Trust me... what you are considering is highly impractical (not impossible) and would require more effort than simply learning MySQL with php.

Answer (score 1):

there are some lightweight db such as `sqlite,access` .

you can find more in  [Lightweight database (SQL or NoSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151070/lightweight-database-sql-or-nosql)