# Save all data in one file or in multiple files?

Tags: java, performance, file

Is it better to save all users data in one file or create a file for each user with his data? Which one is faster?

EDIT: To explain how the file is used, it is managed by my UserManager class which when loading a user is requested, seaches for line [id] where id matches and then reads all the following lines which belong to that id. When it saves user data, it reads the entire file and apply changes, then write the file with changes.

Comment: It's better not to use files.

Comment: Neither. Use a database and that'll be the fastest. If you insist on using files, choose the easier way. If you're not using a database, you aren't really concentrating on performance anyway.

Comment: Guessing this isn't for NoSQL..

Comment: For small apps I would use SQLite. In the end, it's also a file :)

Comment: @Kayaman Databases at the end store their data in files, aren't they ;)

Comment: if your operation and data size is not huge - you can think of ODBC as well. But i would suggest to have a look at this.

Comment: have a look at this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151070/lightweight-database-sql-or-nosql

Comment: Depends on how you use the file afterwards.

Comment: @Dropout added explanation to the question

Comment: @Ladas125 in that case definitely don't use a file for this. This is what relation databases were invented for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not advocate using files to store data. Use a database (NoSQL or Relational).

If you are forced to use a file(Again, bad idea!), then the more performent of the two would be to read from a single file, if you are reading more than one user's info at a time, as you would only have to open a single stream as opposed to multiple streams. The same goes for writing.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @BackSlash, if you only read/write one user at a time, then performance will **NOT** always be the same. See comment below

Comment: `However, if you only read/write one user at a time, then performance will be the same. As you would have to open a stream each time either way.` Not really true. Suppose you have one single file, with informations for lots of users into it: you need to search the file for the specific user, so in the worst case you'll have to read the entire file, and that can be a heavy operation, if the file is really big. If the OP manages one user at time, one small file per user is better than searching into a huge file IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Saving (user) data to a file(s) can be slow. Multiple files or one. It doesn't have to be if you cache your data.

People generally turn to solutions that do this for you, eg a DataBase ;)
They are fast and built for this. Also there are a lot of examples out there.

eg: https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose

Uses node.js (with express, passport, mongoose (mongoDB for node.js), ...)
There is a example in the project
Simply install node.js, mongodb and run the example

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use files. It will be better use to one file. Otherwise you have to open and close file for every user.